# How to draw an arc with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to draw an arc shape with SwiftUI. I was looking for something like a segment modifier to use on Circle(), but I couldn't find one. I should be able to set a start and end angle.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should really check this: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes

And here's a shortcut:

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        MyShape()
    }
}

struct MyShape : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var p = Path()

        p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100, y:100), radius: 50, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(90), clockwise: true)

        return p.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 3, dash: [5, 3], dashPhase: 10))
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've thought there is a out of the box solution for arcs. But with your code I could create everything I need!

Comment: You'r welcome. Note that you also have this other arc method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/3271268-addarc and the strokedPath has other parameters too: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/strokestyle/3276187-init

Comment: Hi, I've just copy pasted this one, but it seems to crash on Xcode 11 Beta 5. Is this an Xcode bug? or are there any changes that we need to do with the code?

Comment: @grey It's a bug in beta 5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57302901/7786555

Comment: Hi @kontiki, it now works with Xcode 11 Beta 6, thank you.

Comment: why isn't it drawing starting from 0 degree to 90 degree clockwise (i.e. filling up the lower right quad of the circle

Comment: what if we want to add color in the arc ???

Answer (score 27):

Another solution to this problem can be done in the following way:

```
Circle()
   .trim(from: 0.25, to: 1.0)
   .rotation(.degrees(-90))
   .stroke(Color.black ,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .butt, dash: [5,3], dashPhase: 10))
   .frame(width: 52, height: 52)
```

Which will produce:

[image]

Depending on what you are looking to do you can choose to do the rotation. This can obviously be extend to be a View Modifier depending on your use case and if its even needed (This seems simple enough).

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Path` to draw the arc

First define path

```
let arc = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                              radius: 60,
                              startAngle: .pi ,
                              endAngle: 0.2,
                              clockwise: true)
```

then

```
            Path(arc.cgPath).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, sorry.

Comment: @user3069232 why do you think it's an incomplete answer? I just copy pasted it into my SwiftUI project and it worked perfectly on the first try. No modification.

Comment: @boxed Glad to hear that it is working for you :)