# Path.fill in Xcode11 beta5 doesn't work anymore

Tags: path, swiftui, xcode11

Path.fill and .stroke of swiftUI in Xcode11 beta5 doesn't work

The code below works fine in Xcode beta4, but it crashes in Xcode beta5, the error information all I get :Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)

Code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path{path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 300, height: 200))
        }.fill(Color.red)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a known issue in Beta 5. Disclosed in their release notes:

> Using the Path structure may cause your app to crash if you’re using
>   the SDKs included in Xcode 11 beta 5. As a result, you may be unable
>   to successfully follow the steps in the Drawing Paths and Shapes
>   tutorial. (53523206)

Comment: Apple's release notes really understate this problem. Path just doesn't work at all with any modifiers (that I have found at least) - causes runtime crash with the error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1bc2b8af4)" - work fully stopped for me!

Comment: @TommP Yeap, big time. I already had an article prepared about advanced animations, and had to postpone it until paths get sorted!